# How do I disable an item in a listbox

Tags: .net, winforms, listbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WinForms ListBox with readonly/disabled items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438168/winforms-listbox-with-readonly-disabled-items)

How do I disable a single item in a listbox? I still want it to show, but the user cant choose it as an item. Do I need to write my own disable() function? If I do, any pointers on how it would work?

Answer (score 0):

see [WinForms ListBox with readonly/disabled items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438168/winforms-listbox-with-readonly-disabled-items)

Comment: See "don't post comments as answers"

Comment: Sorry, I thought linking to the duplicate was an answer not a comment

Comment: Linking is useful but you can link in a comment.