# Block user input from listBox without changing text colour

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, user-controls, listbox

How do you block user input (ie. changing the selected index) on a listbox without changing the text colour, like if you were to just set the enabled property to false on the control?

This is for WinForms.

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: Sorry, I have now clarified that it is WinForms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WinForms ListBox with readonly/disabled items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438168/winforms-listbox-with-readonly-disabled-items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want a default selection from the ListBox that the user *won't* be able to change? My favorite approach to this issue is by Disabling the user from accessing the ListBox. You can do this by adding a [`GotFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus.aspx) event on the ListBox and setting the Focus to another control whenever the ListBox gets focus. Something like this:

```
private void listBox1_GotFocus(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

   this.Select();//set the form as the active control or even this.Focus();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to not do that -- instead, in this situation, only populate the one item you want displayed/selected.

Otherwise, you'll need to:
 - remember the current selection
 - handle OnSelectedIndexChanged
 - reset the selection (handling potential recursion)